# Android Studio can't execute the same query two times?

Tags: java, android, sql

I try to execute a query to a database with android studio. The query works the first time but not the second time. I displayed the two queries but they have no difference.
I found the location of problem : the second query returns nothing. I don't know why.

Can you help me ?

Here the query :

```sql
SELECT 
EMP_ID, EMP_MOT_DE_PASSE, EMP_NOM,EMP_PRENOM, EMP_MAIL, EMP_TELEPHONE 
FROM EMPLOYE 
WHERE EMP_IDENTIFIANT='Identifiant'
```

Here the code :

```java
final ArrayList<String> finalQueryResult = new ArrayList<>();
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    String myurl = "url";
                    myurl = myurl.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                    URL url = new URL(myurl);
                    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    connection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    });

                    connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    connection.getContent();

                    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                    if(!query.contains("INSERT") && !query.contains("DELETE") && !query.contains("UPDATE")) {
                        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                        String str = bufferedReader.readLine();
                        String result = str.substring(5,str.length()-6);
                        JSONArray queryResult = new JSONArray(result);
                        for (int i = 0; i < queryResult.length(); i++) {
                            String lineOfQuery = queryResult.getString(i).substring(1, queryResult.getString(i).length() - 1);
                            finalQueryResult.addAll(Arrays.asList(lineOfQuery.split("[,]")));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    communication = 0;
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code for where you conduct these queries, please

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found an answer.

My problem was that I had just the performances to load the first time. The fact of "change window" just make that the program didn't give me the performances and skipped the query the second time.

So to fix that I just use an AsyncTask not wait by the main thread.

Hope that was helpful.